# Residue at a simple pole

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

I'm studying for complex variable. And, I saw this problem, and, I'm not sure whether the answer is correct or not. Is it correct? I can't follow "the only singular point of the function f outside the curve is $z = \infty$"

Comment: It's not quite correct, $\infty$ is a regular point of the function $f$, but it's a singular point of the differential form $f(z)\,dz$. And that is what counts.

Comment: I really don't know how to solve this problem...

Comment: Are you saying that this answer is totally wrong?

Comment: No, the answer is basically correct, only the formulation is incorrect at that point.

Comment: Could you give me more detailed explanation? If I want to fix that solution, how can I fix it?

Comment: The residue is actually not a property of a function, but a property of a differential form. As long as we're only looking at subsets of $\mathbb{C}$, the difference doesn't show up because we tacitly identify $f(z)$ and $f(z)\,dz$, and $dz$ is regular on $\mathbb{C}$. But the meromorphic differential form $dz$ on the Riemann sphere has a pole at $\infty$, so for applications of the residue theorem to domains that contain $\infty$, we need to make the distinction.

Comment: I think it is beyond my level. Is there any other approach to solve this problem?

Comment: You could also determine the residues at the singularities inside $\gamma$ (these are $0$ and the six zeros of $z^6+1$) and sum them. Or, as robjohn did in his answer, make a substitution that transforms the singularity at $\infty$ into a singularity at $0$ and use the residue theorem in the form it is usually presented first.

Comment: @DanielFischer: the singularity at $z=0$ of the original function, while it can be computed, the closed form is a bit tricky. It is $\frac1{6!}-\frac1{12!}+\frac1{18!}-\dots =1 -\frac13\cos(1) -\frac23\cosh\left(\frac{\sqrt3}2\right) \cos\left(\frac12\right)$

Comment: @robjohn Right. But in view of the other residues, it's better to keep the series form. One will then see that everything except the $1$ cancels. It's of course not the way with the least amount of work.

Answer (score 2):

Substituting $z\mapsto\frac1z$ and letting $\widetilde\gamma=\frac12e^{-it}$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\int_\gamma\frac{e^{1/z}z^5}{z^6+1}\,\mathrm{d}z
&=-\int_{\widetilde\gamma}\frac{e^z}{z(z^6+1)}\,\mathrm{d}z\\
&=2\pi i\operatorname*{Res}_{z=0}\left(\frac{e^z}{z(z^6+1)}\right)\\[6pt]
&=2\pi i
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I have a quick question. Are you just substituted z to 1/z? then, use cauchy's residue theorem? Or are you using the theorem of residue at infinity? I'm not quite understand the first part including $\tilde \gamma$

Comment: The substitution changes $z=2e^{it}$ to $\frac1z=2e^{it}$, which is $z=\frac12e^{-it}$. Then we just compute the integral along the contour, for which I used the residue of the function at $z=0$, the only singularity inside the contour. Note that the new contour is clockwise, which counters the negative brought in by $\mathrm{d}\frac1z=-\frac1{z^2}\,\mathrm{d}z$.

Comment: By substituting z to 1/z, we will have $\frac{z e^z}{z^6+1}$ I think that it is just typo. Is this correct?

Comment: You need to include the $-\frac1{z^2}\,\mathrm{d}z$